# Svg files made with illustrator comes black color when imported to blender

Tags: 3d-view

I am a beginner of blender and i want to make my image a 3D logo,
I have converted it into svg using adobe illustrator  but when i import it into blender it only shows the shape with only one color (Black)
Please Kindly help me i have tried changing different options while saving it but instead worsens 
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide screenshots? Try converting the SVG Curve into a Mesh, SVGs are imported as curves.

Comment: perhaps share your svg file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/   but anyway a svg will only be imported colored in black